# How to solve nestjs fastify error TypeError: response.status(...).json is not a function

Tags: nestjs-fastify

TypeError: response.status(...).json is not a function
at HttpExceptionFilter.catch (/home/muhammedali/Documents/100haryt_v2/src/common/http/http-exception.filter.ts:23:29)
at ExceptionsHandler.invokeCustomFilters (/home/muhammedali/Documents/100haryt_v2/node_modules/@nestjs/core/exceptions/exceptions-handler.js:33:26)
at ExceptionsHandler.next (/home/muhammedali/Documents/100haryt_v2/node_modules/@nestjs/core/exceptions/exceptions-handler.js:13:18)

Answer (score 3):

```
  response
      .status(status)
      .json({
        statusCode: status,
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
        path: request.url,
      });
```

instead of using the above code. try to change like as below

```
  response
      .status(status)
      .send({
        statusCode: status,
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
        path: request.url,
      });
```